# Найти наибольшее количество одинаковых значений

Tags: c++, c

Существует огромное количество задач с нахождением одинаковых значений в массиве или между *переменнами*. Написал код, который ищет общее количество одинаковых цифр. Нужно дописать код чтобы он искал не общее количество одинаковых значений, а максимальное количество одинаковых цифр, допустим у нас имеется набор массива в виде: 1,5,1,1,2,2; Максимальное количество одинаковых значений равно 3, так как у нас имеется три единицы(1). Сам код ищущий общее количество одинаковых значений:

```
int srav() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers_var + 1; i++) {
        if (arr[a] == arr[i]) {
            ravni++;            
        }
        if (i == numbers_var) {
            a++;
        }
    }
    return ravni;
```

`

Comment: `c++` *от фонаря* проставлено? Задачи на поиск повторений -- это задачи на создание ассоциативных массивов (если не сильно простое что-то, типа вашего примера, где O(n^2) не влияет ни на что).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берем массив `digs[0]`, далее идем по цифрам, увеличивая соответствующий `digs[i]` для цифры `i`, ну, а потом находим в массиве максимальное значение.

Код дописать или и так идея понятна?

Что-то типа этого:

```
int digs[10] = {0};
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) digs[a[i]]++;
int idx = 0, max = digs[0];
for(int i = 1; i < 10; ++i) 
    if (digs[i] > max) { idx = i; max = digs[i]; }
```

В `idx` после этого - цифра с максимальным повтором (если несколько - наименьшая), в `max` - количество ее повторов...

**Update**
Раз речь идет о числах...

Решение для C - например, отсортировав массив, пройтись по нему с запоминанием, какой элемент встретится (теперь это будет подряд) большее количество раз.

В C++ можно поступить проще - воспользоваться точно так же, как описано для цифр, готовым `map`:

```
map<int,int> digs;
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) digs[a[i]]++;
auto i = digs.begin();
int val = i->first, max = i->second;
for(auto i: digs) 
    if (i->second > max) { val = i; max = i->second; }
```

Comment: @Abyx Ну, если человек не отличает цифры от чисел, то... В условии сказано четко - **цифры**...

Comment: Как говорится оговорился, но все же большее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: На самом деле я просил количество одинаковых значений, я ясно это выразил в примере, но видимо из-за маленькой оговорки меня не поняли, ну или принципиально это сделали.

Comment: Если бы вы хотя бы в примере привели хоть одно двузначное значение - было бы понятнее. Я понял вас именно так, что вам нужны именно **цифры**.

Comment: Посмотрите обновленный ответ.